# How to categorize 'perfect' and 'dead'?

Tags: adjectives, category

Is there a term for adjectives like *perfect*, *ubiquitous* and *dead*, that permit only certain modifiers? They're essentially absolute, but not quite binary.

There's no range of ubiquity -- something is either everywhere or it isn't. Gems aren't *very perfect*. A witch can't literally be more dead than another witch, though of course she can be most sincerely dead.

A property of such words seems to be that you can approach them as a limit, but not exceed or quantize them. So we might use *almost* or *nearly*, but not *slightly* or *extremely*. Almost perfect? Sure. Slightly perfect? Nope.

Is there such a category, or am I just dreaming one up, stretching to fit?

Comment: Related: [Graded/ungraded adjectives and grading/non-grading adverbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/483793/80039)

Comment: @ColleenV - Thanks. Once you know that there is a category, there's good information out there.

Answer (score 2):

They are called ‘non-gradable adjectives’ (or ‘absolute adjectives’).

> #### Non-gradable adjectives: absolute adjectives
>
> Some adjectives are non-gradable. For example, something can't be *a bit finished* or *very finished*. You can't be *a bit dead* or *very dead*. These adjectives describe absolute qualities. To make them stronger we have to use modifiers like *absolutely*, *totally* or *completely*:
>
> - *Thank you, I love it! It's absolutely perfect!*
> - *Their farm was totally destroyed by a tornado.*
> - *My work is completely finished. Now I can relax.*

[[British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/adjectives-gradable-and-non-gradable)]

Comment: Well, something could be [mostly dead](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0093779/characters/nm0000345) or [very illegal](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/84155/9161). I don’t think absolute adjectives are as absolute as many definitions make them out to be; they just have ungradable tendencies.

Comment: *Popular Science* - Feb 1973 - Page 98 "You hit the starter, and to your dismay the engine turns over slowly, as if the battery were almost dead. But the car finally starts, and you drive off."  2012 *Excursions with Kierkegaard*, p.180 "Yet perhaps he is already somewhat dead, and so does have a grave close by. Can he commune with himself as one communes with the dead?"

Comment: I think it would be wise to include these exceptions, as a caveat to the questioner.